# Excel: Evaluating data by groups established by another column

Tags: excel

Update: I ended up using the following formula in the Requirement Met? column.
`IF(COUNT(INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(B2,B:B,0):INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(B2,B:B,1)))=COUNTA(INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(B2,B:B,0):INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(B2,B:B,1))),"Met","Not Met")`

I have a list of requirements which may be verified by one or more documents. I'm trying to find a way for Excel to evaluate whether or not a requirement is met by looking at all of the relevant documents' release dates. For example, if a requirement has only one verifying document and that document has been released, that requirement can be considered to be met. However, if a requirement has three related documents, and only 2 have been released, the requirement has not yet been met.

| Group | Requirement | Verifying Document | Document Number | Release Date | Requirement Met? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1235 | 79K85956 Summary Report for Modifications | 79K85956 | 12/13/2020 | Yes |
| 1 | 1-7412 | 79K13345 Test Report for Materials | 79K13345 | 6/14/2019 | Yes |
| 1 | 1-961 | 79K32121 Purchase Order for Supplier | 79K32121 | 12/13/2017 | Yes |
| 2 | 2-123 | Laboratory A Certification 79K21314 | 79K21314 | 5/11/2016 | No |
| 2 | 2-123 | Laboratory B Certification 79K21315 | 79K21315 | 6/14/2019 | No |
| 2 | 2-123 | Laboratory C Certification 79K21316 | 79K21316 |  | No |

Ultimately, I would like to determine how many requirements are met by each group in each month, but I think I can do that easily enough with a PivotTable if I can just figure out a formula for the "Requirement Met?" column.

Previously, I stumbled into a formula that does something similar in another situation, but can't figure out how to make it work this time. In that case, I was looking at multiple rows grouped by the Change Notice column and looking for a key word in the Workflow Step Name column.

I used `=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(B2,B:B,0)):INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(B2,B:B,1)),"Yes"),"No","Yes")` for the **Clean Release?** column.

| Simplified Workflow Step Name | Role w/o NA | Workflow Step Name | Change Notice | Release Status | Role | User | Action Taken | Time In | Time Out | Clean Release? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Configuration Review | Configuration Reviewer | Engineering Document Release Configuration Review | CN00035 | Released | Configuration Reviewer | smitha | Rejected | 5/4/2016 | 5/5/2016 | No |
| Back Fix from CR | Author | Incorporate Conformance Comments | CN00035 | Released | N/A | williamss | Completed | 5/5/2016 | 5/12/2016 | No |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in Google Sheets, but I think it should work the same in Excel:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(FILTER($E:$E, $A:$A=$A1))=0,"Yes","No")
```

Columns A and E are the ones corresponding to `Group` and `Release Date`.

It's basically counting how many blank cells are in `Release Date` but only for the rows that have the same value in `Group` than the current row (row 1 in my example, of course you need to expand it to all rows), and then prints "Yes" only if that number is 0, "No" otherwise.

Comment: There's apparently no Excel 2016 equivalent for FILTER, which is fun. I appreciate your answer, though.